# Combination of hotkeys as shortcut keys in excel userform

Tags: excel, vba, keyboard-shortcuts, userform

How can we assign shortcut key like ctrl + enter to commandbutton in userform in excel ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the accelerator property of the control. Go to the properties window of the commandbutton and in the accelerator property, enter a letter which exists in the commandbutton caption. For example, if the commandbutton caption is "Save", you could put the letter S. You'll notice that the letter S in the word Save on the commandbutton is now underlined. The keyboard shortcut for the commandbutton is now Alt+S.